# convert a date to a different timezone date object react datePicker

Tags: javascript, date, react-datepicker

I am using a component called react-datepicker

My datePicker is returning a date like this, Im in Colorado.

```
"Thu Oct 27 2022 02:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)"
```

When i convert this to UTC i get this

```
"2022-10-27T08:00:00Z"
```

I need to be able to set my timezone to America/New_York, so my datepicker can give me an object like this,

```
"Thu Oct 27 2022 02:00:00 GMT-0400 (New_York or whatever its actually called)"
```

This way when I convert to utc I can get this output below

```
"2022-10-27T06:00:00Z"
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Also is it possible for me to convert this

```
"Thu Oct 27 2022 02:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)"
```

to this

```
"Thu Oct 27 2022 02:00:00 GMT-0400 (New_York or whatever its actually called)"
```

Here is my component

```
                                    <DatePicker
                                      key={index}
                                       showPopperArrow={false}
                                       onChange={(date) => { 
                                        console.log('date', date)
                                        // this shows Thu Oct 27 2022 02:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time), I need to be able to convert this to Thu Oct 27 2022 02:00:00 GMT-0400 (New_York, or any timezone for that matter)
                                       selected={new Date(wkday?.trigger_time)}
                                       customInput={<CustomInputWeekdayTimes />}
                                       showTimeSelect
                                       showTimeSelectOnly
                                       timeIntervals={60}
                                       timeCaption="Time"
                                     />
```

Comment: Please check this, May be it can help.
new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});
we can pass date string to the Date constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I achieved what I wanted using moment-timezone

```
//date coming in like this Sat Oct 29 2022 02:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
const applyOffset = date.setTime(date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60_000);
  const actualTime = new Date(applyOffset).toISOString().replace("Z", "")
  const toTz = momentt.tz(actualTime, timezone).format()
  const getUTCTime = momentt.utc(toTz).format()
```

Note timezone variable getting passed to momentt.tz(actualTime, timezone).format() can be any named timezone like "America/New_York" or "America/Chicago"

When I console.log(getUTCTime) I get 2022-10-29T06:00:00Z If I make timezone "America/New_York"

Here is the actual datePicker component

```
    <DatePicker
       key={index}
       showPopperArrow={false}
       onChange={(date) => { 
        const applyOffset = date.setTime(date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60_000);
        const actualTime = new Date(applyOffset).toISOString().replace("Z", "")
        const toTz = momentt.tz(actualTime, timezone).format()
        const getUTCTime = momentt.utc(toTz).format()
        
         //console.log("moment.utc", momentt.utc(date).format())
         // const incomingDate = new Date(date).getTime()
         //const ourStartDate = new Date(startDate).getTime()

         //  if(incomingDate < ourStartDate) {
         //  const newD = new Date(date)
        // const sevenDaysAhead = newD.setDate(newD.getDate() + 7)
                                        return setFormObj(
                                          {...formObj,
                                             repeatCampaignWeekdayTimes: {...formObj?.repeatCampaignWeekdayTimes, [el]: formObj?.repeatCampaignWeekdayTimes[el].map((obj) => {if(obj.uid === wkday.uid) { return {trigger_time: getUTCTime, uid: obj.uid, triggered: false} } else { return obj } })}
                                            })
                                     
                                        }}
           selected={new Date(wkday?.trigger_time)}
           customInput={<CustomInputWeekdayTimes />}
           showTimeSelect
           showTimeSelectOnly
           timeIntervals={60}
           timeCaption="Time"
              />
```